# React - ReactHtmlParser returns an [object Object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, string

I am using ReactHtmlParser and returning string as html tag

**JavaScript_Lessons_Objects.js**

```
function JavaScriptLessonObject() {

    const one = "Robby ";
    
    return (
        [
            {
                title: [<div><p className={jsStyle.title}>Overview</p></div>],
            },

            {
                titleName: "JS Output",
                iconName: faDotCircle,
                description: [
                    <span className={jsStyle.yourClass}>{one}</span>,
                    `<p> advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old. </p>`
                ],
            },

        ]
    );
}
```

**Lesson.jsx**

```
<div className={less.description}>
    <p>
        {
            ReactHtmlParser(this.props.lesson[this.state.indexDescription]["description"])
        }
    </p>
</div>
```

Please note, apart from the line, I use `<span className={jsStyle.yourClass}>{one}</span>` which takes the quality of the name "Robby", but instead of the name I get [object Object], https://ibb.co/GWGWMZ2
But when I remove the ReactHtmlParser i.e. `this.props.lesson[this.state.indexDescription]["description"]` I get the name https://ibb.co/6b3YVzc but as you understood already html tags inside the line do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work like a charm.

```
`<span className={jsStyle.yourClass}>${one}</span>`
```

Actually, ReactHtmlParser thinks `{one}` as a javascript object, in order to send its value to html code, we will need to convert its value, using `${...}` like syntax.

Comment: Ahh really! i tried this approach `<span className={jsStyle.yourClass}>${one}</span>` but without quotes, thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear that! It would be great if you can upvote it as well!